# How to Resolve? Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling

I'm encountering recurring errors in my several Spring Boot applications startup, and I'm seeking guidance on how to address and resolve these issues. The error messages are as follows:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
ERROR 37995 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
ERROR 38057 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
ERROR 38082 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
ERROR 38090 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

I'd appreciate any insights, suggestions, or additional debugging techniques to identify and resolve these recurring errors in my Spring Boot applications startup. If there's additional information needed, please let me know. Thank you in advanced!

1. Enabled debug mode in IntelliJ IDEA by adding -Dspring.profiles.active=debug to the JVM options.
2. Started the Spring Boot application in debug mode.
3. Analyzed the debugging information, but the error persists
4. Added some dependencied

Answer (score 1):

To see debugging information add this to your application.properties

```
debug=true
```